# Aplicacion Java con Conexion Base de datos

Tags: java

He realizado una Aplicación en Java con conexión a una BD en Mysql, todo trabaja perfecto en el IDE tanto en Eclipse como En Intellij, pero al compilarlo en .jar me muestra un error que no encuentra el conector de mysql.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lo incluiste o esta en la misma carpeta que el jar?

Comment: Lo incluí en el IDE y en el IDE me funciona bien lo que cuando lo compilo como .jar me da error en el conector de la Base de Datos

Comment: Comparte el error que tienes, de otro modo es casi imposible ayudarte.

Comment: El Error que me da es el siguiente: java.sql.SQL.Exception: No suitable driver found for jdbc

Comment: @DavidCordero agrega el código que estas realizando en tu pregunta, por favor revisa [ask] para que edites en base a esta información tu pregunta.

Comment: Primero que tecnología de java estas utilizando, aplicación de escritorio, JSF, Spring Boot?, si estas trabajando con aplicación de escritorio, java te copila y deja 3 carpetas que acompañan al JAR entre las cuales se encuentra el driver de MYSQL.